# mutt hangs when connecting to SMTP server on an unreliable connection

Tags: mutt, connectivity

When sending email with mutt and connecting to an external SMTP server, on an unreliable connection (e.g., bad Wifi), it often happens that mutt remains stuck at the "Connecting to..." stage indefinitely. Sometimes this eventually times out and sending the email fails and can be retried, but sometimes it never seems to time out. I would also expect to have a way to cancel the sending of the message with Ctrl-C (and try again afterwards), but this usually does not work at that stage.

So I end up having to kill mutt, and dig up the email I had composed from mutt's temporary folder, in order to try sending it again.

I'm curious whether this is a well-known problem and whether there a way to fix this. For instance, can mutt be configured to have a shorter connection timeout that's actually respected, or some other way to cancel send in a reliable way?